# How to flip which side a progress bar begins at with CSS

Tags: html, css

I found some code online for a progress bar which uses a div class and then uses CSS to style it, fill it, color it, and round the edges. Well it originally was a horizontal bar and I needed a vertical one, so i flipped it around. Changed a little of the edge rounding, and now have a vertical one. Only issue is that when putting in the percent you want it to be full in the div class, it loads from the top of the bar rather than the bottom. I have tried to the best of my ability to get it to flip with no luck. If you can either fix this issue or have any useful advice please let me know. Thanks in advance! I will first post the div class and then they styling.

```html
<div class="meter red">
  <span style="height: 20%"></span>
</div>
```

And now the styling

```css
.meter { 
  height: 30vh;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background: #555;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow   : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  box-shadow        : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }

.meter > span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
         -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
             border-top-right-radius: 20px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
          -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    center right,
    center right,
    color-stop(0, rgb(43,194,83)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(84,240,84))
    );
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
  -webkit-box-shadow: 
    inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 
    inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red > span {
  background-color: #f0a3a3;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,
    left top,left bottom,color-stop(0.#f0a3a3),color-stop(1, #f42323));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
}

.meter > span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-image: 
    -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, 
      color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
      color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), 
      color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
      color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
      color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent)
    );
  background-image: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(
      -45deg, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
      transparent 25%, 
      transparent 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
      transparent 75%, 
      transparent
    );
  background-image: 
    -moz-linear-gradient(
      -45deg, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
      transparent 25%, 
      transparent 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
      transparent 75%, 
      transparent
    );
  background-image: 
    -ms-linear-gradient(
      -45deg, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
      transparent 25%, 
      transparent 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
      transparent 75%, 
      transparent
    );
  background-image: 
    -o-linear-gradient(
      -45deg, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
      transparent 25%, 
      transparent 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
      transparent 75%, 
      transparent
    );
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
  -moz-background-size:    50px 50px;
  background-size:         50px 50px;
  -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
         -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
             border-top-right-radius: 8px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
          -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
              border-top-left-radius: 20px;
           border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the top property as `100 - height`. Example:

```
<div class="meter red">
    <span style="height: 20%; top: 80%;"></span>
</div>
<div class="meter red">
    <span style="height: 60%; top: 40%;"></span>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
I hope you don't mind, but I took the liberty of modifying your progress bar.
I've removed the "vh" units size since it's not widely supported (especially in IE) and simply used pixels.
Also I've changed the positioning of your child element to be absolute. This allows it to be positioned anywhere inside the container (see bottom).

This means that updating the height will now properly go from bottom to top in just one property.
See modified version here:
http://jsbin.com/kiseyocife/1/edit?html,output

You mentioned you want to update your progress programatically, so here's how to do it:

```
document.getElementById("progress-load").style.height = nrVal +"%"
```

nrVal in this case can be 0-100 but it won't break if it goes out of bounds.

Comment: That did the trick! Would you mind explaining the relationship between top and height? I plan on making this a constant update progress bar based off of constantly updating values from a database and want to fully understand this solution you gave?

Comment: Also I tired to set it my top: like this and it did not work, but when doing a numberical values such as 30% it works. Can you explain that? top:(100-height)%;

Comment: Again thank you, you went above and beyond. I see the changes you made, was planning to do the vh later on, but glad you reminded me. Also for updating progress I understand the left hand side of the line, but the right hand side, what does nrVal represent?

Comment: nrVal is a simply a number. When you add a number to a string, javascript automatically casts the number to string and concatenates them so it becomes "30" + "%" -> "30%".

Comment: Hey man sorry to bother again, I got the bars to work great in chrome and firerfox but they appear completly different in IE 11. No striping, different color of red, no rounding of edges, basically a red rectangle. Any idea why? And i say bars because i made multiple of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68967/discussion-between-user3072210-and-george-nemes).

Comment: My chat is no longer useable, you avaiable still hung up on this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not rotate the container 90 or 270 degrees?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Tried a tranform rotate earlier today with no success.